# How to make site vertical scrollable and dragable?

Tags: html, css, scroll, draggable

i found a site with a very interesting navigation.
The content is scrollable and dragable in vertical direction.

The art of navigation feels like i am using it on a tablet.

See here:  http://www.abm.at/de/home

Is there any library for it?
Does anybody know?

And also very interesting is, that the content is listed like iframes, where you can scroll in it. 
But there is no iframe visible in the sourcecode.
**So, whats that? How to do the same?**

**EDIT 1:**
I've found this for scroll with dragging: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Dragscrollable

Comment: That has got to be one of the most horrible ways I have seen my make a navigation for a site. Yuk. Fair enough make your website scrollable for people on a tablet, but dragging when I have a perfectly good mouse is annoying as hell.

Comment: @KingCronus it is ALSO scrollable :)

Comment: But why? I have two 22 inch widescreen monitors precisely because scrolling is annoying. I don't argue that the site is pretty, but I was giving my subjective opinion that it would annoy me!

Comment: @KingCronus Why? Because its interesting me. You have TWO 22 inch widescreen, nice, but - sorry for this comment - you are not the standard. here is not the place to discuss about subjective opinion. anyway, thanks for it.

Comment: I'm fairly confident I would also find it annoying on my 14 inch laptop to be fair. Each to their own I suppose.

Comment: its just a nice effect for special content. i thought about sites which contains only a timeline explanation. 
Like  
**|Apple 1984(horizontally scrollable in it)|Microsoft|Aplle 2012(horizontally scrollable content in it.)|**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery library, find below a link with full details

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

It is very simple to use and implement

```
$(function()
{
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

Comment: The library jscrollpane is for scrolling the "iframe-like" divs, right? And for make the whole site dragable to use it like on a tablet?

Comment: it is for scrolling only, regarding the dragging i think you need to use additional plugin